# Azure web-apps へのrest操作

Tags: azure, rest

azure Docsに rest apiでの操作方法があります。
(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/rest/api/appservice/web-apps)

「Create or Update」ではアプリの作成・更新が可能とありますが、
(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}?api-version=2021-02-01
```

クイックスタートのようにPHPのruntime等をを指定する方法がわかりません。
(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/app-service/quickstart-php)

```
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app-name> --runtime 'PHP|7.4' --deployment-local-git
```

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。

以下のように、App ServiceのsiteConfigで指定が可能です。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/azure-rest-api-app-service/